# Brother QL-700 Printed Image Size Reduced

Tags: printer

I have a Brother QL-700 label printer that is functioning under Windows and Linux.  However, everything printed to it under Linux comes out about 20% smaller than when printed from Windows.  I have tested this printing things both from Chrome and Inkscape, in both cases where the image to be printed is carefully crafted to fit the label precisely.  Does anyone have experience with this, and have any idea how to stop the Linux QL-700 driver from shrinking the image?

[image]
On the left, printed with Windows.  On the right, Linux.  Same content, both using Chrome.

If the image doesn't load, here's the link:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/D04zV.jpg

As requested by a commenter, here is the output of `lpoptions -l`:

```
PageSize/Media Size: 17x54 17x87 23x23 29x42 29x90 38x90 39x48 52x29 60x86 *62x29 62x100 12Dia 24Dia 58Dia 12X1 29X1 38X1 50X1 54X1 62X1 12X2 29X2 38X2 50X2 54X2 62X2 12X3 29X3 38X3 50X3 54X3 62X3 12X4 29X4 38X4 50X4 54X4 62X4
BrMargin/Feed(invalid for Die-Cut tape): *3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30
BrPriority/Quality: *BrSpeed BrQuality
BrCutLabel/Cut every: 0 *1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30
BrCutAtEnd/Cut at end: OFF *ON
BrTrimtape/Trim tape after data: *OFF ON
BrMirror/Mirror Printing: *OFF ON
BrHalftonePattern/Halftone: BrBinary BrDither *BrErrorDiffusion
BrBrightness/Brightness: 50 49 48 47 46 45 44 43 42 41 40 39 38 37 36 35 34 33 32 31 30 29 28 27 26 25 24 23 22 21 20 19 18 17 16 15 14 13 12 11 10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 *0 -1 -2 -3 -4 -5 -6 -7 -8 -9 -10 -11 -12 -13 -14 -15 -16 -17 -18 -19 -20 -21 -22 -23 -24 -25 -26 -27 -28 -29 -30 -31 -32 -33 -34 -35 -36 -37 -38 -39 -40 -41 -42 -43 -44 -45 -46 -47 -48 -49 -50
BrContrast/Contrast: 50 49 48 47 46 45 44 43 42 41 40 39 38 37 36 35 34 33 32 31 30 29 28 27 26 25 24 23 22 21 20 19 18 17 16 15 14 13 12 11 10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 *0 -1 -2 -3 -4 -5 -6 -7 -8 -9 -10 -11 -12 -13 -14 -15 -16 -17 -18 -19 -20 -21 -22 -23 -24 -25 -26 -27 -28 -29 -30 -31 -32 -33 -34 -35 -36 -37 -38 -39 -40 -41 -42 -43 -44 -45 -46 -47 -48 -49 -50
```

Comment: add to your post what options are shown by `lpoptions -p XX -l` where XX is the name of the printer?

Comment: Is the selected PageSize (the one with an asterisk next to it: `*62x29`) the correct size for the label?

Comment: Yes, it is the size of the die-cut label loaded in the printer.